# Animate canvas Line on Kivy

Tags: python, animation, canvas, line, kivy

I have an array with x and y positions. I want to show these points linking a line successively for each point, then, creating an animation. It is just like a path tracking whose trail is the line. I'm using python-kivy to try to display it.

I couldn't find any help on google.

There's a button that triggers this animation.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import Line
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color
from time import sleep

x_moves = [250, 250.4305, 249.8804, 246.0923, 239.7496, 233.8188, 225.7797, 215.8385, 205.8413, 196.6497, 189.7026, 181.2445, 174.9816, 171.9882, 166.1171, 161.6505, 159.9929, 161.1338, 164.853, 168.2874, 170.768, 178.6918, 184.5233, 190.0262, 195.607, 202.0255, 210.5954, 216.1031, 219.6285, 224.9134, 230.2314, 237.7017, 243.7408, 250.5839, 256.2949]
y_moves = [250, 240.0093, 230.0244, 220.7697, 213.0386, 204.9872, 199.0396, 197.9567, 197.7209, 201.6598, 208.8527, 214.1875, 221.9834, 231.5249, 239.62, 248.567, 258.4287, 268.3634, 277.6461, 287.0379, 296.7253, 302.8256, 310.9492, 319.299, 327.5969, 335.2652, 340.4185, 348.7651, 358.1231, 366.6125, 375.0812, 381.7291, 389.6996, 396.9915, 405.2003]

class my_App(App):
    def build(self):
        self.widget = Widget()
        self.widget.on_touch_down = self.touch
        with self.widget.canvas:
            Color(0, 1, 0, 1) #just initial config
            Line(points = [0,0,500,0,500,500,0,500], close = True) #just initial config
        return self.widget

    def touch(self, touch): #executes the animation
        pts = []
        for i in range(len(x_moves)):
            pts.append(x_moves[i])
            pts.append(y_moves[i])
            self.widget.canvas.add(Line(points = pts))
            sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = my_App()
    obj.run()
```

This is my code that doesn't work. But that's the idea.

Comment: add an error message? im not sure i understand exactly what isnt working

Comment: actually, the code works, but in this way, the animation is not shown. only after the loop runs, the canvas is updated.

Comment: thankyou :) thats the sort of thing you should include in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're blocking the UI from updating because your function doesn't return and you use `sleep()`. For obvious reasons, Kivy can't do anything while your code is running. If you want to wait before running some more code, you can use Kivy's [`Clock`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html) for this. Then Kivy will be able to update the screen.

But you should probably just look at Kivy's [`Animation`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.animation.html), which is built to do this much better.

Comment: Yeah... sleep() there is a dumb thing. I just put to make the idea clear. But nice to hear about the `Clock` and I couldn't find a way to implement `Animation` in a way to solve the problem. I'm gonna try the `Clock` and give feedback.